# Wrong ClamAV update?

Tags: 18.04, updates, clamav

I have followed this steps to install ClamAV

1.

```
sudo apt install clamav
```

2.

```
sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam
```

3.

```
sudo freshclam
```

4.

```
sudo systemctl start clamav-freshclam
```

But after step 3 I received this output

```
Tue Oct 16 05:08:35 2018 -> ClamAV update process started at Tue Oct 16 05:08:35 2018
Tue Oct 16 05:08:54 2018 -> Downloading main.cvd [100%]
Tue Oct 16 05:09:10 2018 -> main.cvd updated (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Tue Oct 16 05:09:10 2018 -> *Can't query main.58.93.1.0.6810BC8A.ping.clamav.net
Tue Oct 16 05:09:18 2018 -> Downloading daily.cvd [100%]
Tue Oct 16 05:09:29 2018 -> daily.cvd updated (version: 25040, sigs: 2122685, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Tue Oct 16 05:09:29 2018 -> *Can't query daily.25040.93.1.0.6810BC8A.ping.clamav.net
Tue Oct 16 05:09:29 2018 -> Downloading bytecode.cvd [100%]
Tue Oct 16 05:09:31 2018 -> bytecode.cvd updated (version: 327, sigs: 91, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Tue Oct 16 05:09:31 2018 -> *Can't query bytecode.327.93.1.0.6810BC8A.ping.clamav.net
Tue Oct 16 05:09:38 2018 -> Database updated (6689025 signatures) from db.local.clamav.net (IP: 104.16.188.138)
Tue Oct 16 05:09:38 2018 -> !NotifyClamd: Can't find or parse configuration file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
```

I don't know if this has been a successful update or I should do anything more...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't configured clamav, hence the error message:

> !NotifyClamd: Can't find or parse configuration file
>   /etc/clamav/clamd.conf

**But that's ok** it's just a !Notify.  **You don't need to do anything more if you don't want to.**

The defaults for clamav are good, and you were able to download all the signatures, so it's working.

If you want to customise your installation, then read [`man clamd.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/clamd.conf)

Comment: Thanks, I configured my options and works perfect... solved